# Ansible: iterate over a list in dictionary as condition

Tags: loops, ansible, conditional-statements, lvm

I created a role to create LVM VG(s) and to make it fully idempotent and fault proof i want to verify that the PV(s) exist and that the VG is not already defined.

**roles/lvm/vars/main.yml**

```
---
lvm_vgs:
  - vg_name: drbdpool
    vg_pvs: "{{ vg_drbdpool_pvs }}"
```

**host_vars/hostname**

```
---
vg_drbdpool_pvs: ['sdc1', 'sdd1']
```

**roles/lvm/tasks/main.yml**

```
- name: Create LVM VG(s)
  lvg:
    vg: "{{ item.vg_name }}"
    pvs: "{% for disk in item.vg_pvs %}/dev/{{ disk }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}"
    state: present
  when:
    - item.vg_name not in ansible_lvm.vgs
    - "{% for disk in item.vg_pvs %}ansible_devices[{{ disk | truncate(-1) }}]['partitions']{{ disk }} is defined{% endfor %}"
  with_items: "{{ lvm_vgs }}"
```

To achieve this i added the condition `"{% for disk in item.vg_pvs %}ansible_devices[{{ disk | truncate(-1) }}]['partitions']{{ disk }} is defined{% endfor %}"` but it doesn't work and i always get the following error:

> TASK [lvm : Create LVM VG(s)] **************************************************
>       fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check '{% for disk in item.vg_pvs %}ansible_devices[{{ disk | truncate(-1) }}]['partitions']{{ disk }} is defined{% endfor %}' failed. The error was: unexpected '.'\n  line 1\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/roles/lvm/tasks/main.yml': line 80, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Create LVM VG(s)\n  ^ here\n"}

How can I verify that the PVs (partitions) exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[techraf's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2947502/techraf) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43681129/1878773) brought me to the solution.

```
- name: Create LVM VG(s)
  lvg:
    vg: "{{ item.vg_name }}"
    pvs: "{% for disk in item.vg_pvs %}/dev/{{ disk }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}"
    state: present
  when:
    - item.vg_name not in ansible_lvm.vgs
    - partition_exists.split(';')
  with_items: "{{ lvm_vgs }}"
  vars:
    partition_exists: "{% for disk in item.vg_pvs %}ansible_devices[{{ disk | truncate(-1) }}]['partitions']{{ disk }} is defined{% if not loop.last %};{% endif %}{% endfor %}"
  tags: ['storage', 'lvm']
```

As `item.vg_pvs` may have more than one element, the variable `partition_exists` needs to be created as list.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible assumes the argument of `when` is a bare Jinja2 expression (it implicitly adds `{{` `}}` braces around), so you cannot use a statement `{% ... %}` inside.

A workaround is to define a variable in the task and use the variable name as the condition:

```
- name: Create LVM VG(s)
  lvg:
    vg: "{{ item.vg_name }}"
    pvs: "{% for disk in item.vg_pvs %}/dev/{{ disk }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}"
    state: present
  when:
    - item.vg_name not in ansible_lvm.vgs
    - partition_exists
  with_items: "{{ lvm_vgs }}"
  vars:
    partition_exists: "{% for disk in item.vg_pvs %}ansible_devices[{{ disk | truncate(-1) }}]['partitions']{{ disk }} is defined{% endfor %}"
```

<sup>I have no way to test your actual condition, so I leave it intact.</sup>